# Написать SOAP client

Tags: php, битрикс, soap

Добрый день.
Вот только недавно стал разбираться как работает сервис.
Имеется написанный SOAP server. http://api.kartoteka.ru/
Поиск компаний по инн.
Я ввожу инн и мне в ответ возвращает полную информацию по нему.
Необходимо сперва отправить запрос на авторизацию.
Вот ссылка http://api.kartoteka.ru/search/v2/soap/search.wsdl
Вот сам запрос из примера

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNyK9.png

   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY5UE.png

> Авторизоваться под учетными данными логин: search_api_demo, пароль:
>   search_api_demo и получить идентификатор сессии.

Пишу так

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
$client = new SoapClient("http://api.kartoteka.ru/search/v1/soap/search.wsdl", array('trace'=>1));
$id_session =  $client->login("search_api_demo","search_api_demo");
```

так чего то не прокатывает.

Вот 2й вариант

```
 ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
$client = new SoapClient("http://api.kartoteka.ru/search/v1/soap/search.wsdl",
    array(
        'login'     => "search_api_demo",
        'password'  => "search_api_demo"
    )
);
$client->__getFunction(); 
// так возвращает список всех функций http://i.imgur.com/2zqzjv4.png
```

Но вызвать какую либо из функций ни как не получается.

Подскажите пожалуйста, чего я не не так делаю.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: не прокатывает - это что значит?

Comment: $getInfoUser = new SoapClient("http://api.kartoteka.ru/search/v2/soap/search.wsdl");
$sessionId = $getInfoUser->login(array('login' => "search_api_demo", "password"=>"search_api_demo")); Вот так заработало. Не правильно передал параметры.

Comment: Только вот не долго пришлось радоваться. Для того чтобы вызвать метод для поиска по инн необходимо передать id сессии и инн. Ни как не могу понять какой должен быть формат передачи параметров.
Вот все используемые методы - http://i.imgur.com/l3xH6ei.png. Для поиска по инн вызывается метод searchByRequisite. 
Открыл данную ссылку в SoapUI - http://i.imgur.com/m70mTBN.png

Comment: Подскажите пож. как правильно передать параметры.
Вот один из вариантов:
$params =  array(
    "searchRequestType"=>array(
        'sessionId'=>$sessionId->session->id,
        'inn'=>'7710684990'
    )
);

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/p4eKS85.png

Comment: Это не вопрос по тегу битрикс. Вообще в вопросе нет ничего про битрикс.